# zip_code makes location inaccurate

Tags: google-geocoding-api

I'm using [this](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-python/) library (just a wrapper) to work with **google geocode api**

I discovered that in some cases, result returned for almost same addresses - the only difference is including/omitting zipcode - is different.

example:

```
import googlemaps
gmaps = googlemaps.Client(key="secret")

addr_w_zip = "23 Commonwealth Avenue, Chestnut Hill, MA 02467, US"
addr_no_zip = "23 Commonwealth Avenue, Chestnut Hill, MA, US"

res_w_zip = gmaps.geocode(addr_w_zip)
res_no_zip = gmaps.geocode(addr_no_zip)

# these are the results I get:
# with zip: 42.340062300, -71.167352500
# no zip: 42.340072600, -71.167537600
# coordinates where zip is used are incorrect (building next to the correct one)
```

Am I missing something or should be zip code omitted to get more accurate results ? Or should it be used only if substantial part of search query address is missing (like city and state)?

EDIT:
Any tips, best practices and gottchas are also welcome.

Comment: It looks like performing the [request with the zip code](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=23%20Commonwealth%20Avenue%2C%20Chestnut%20Hill%2C%20MA%2002467%2C%20US) produces a result of type "street_address" whereas the [request without the zip code](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?&address=23%20Commonwealth%20Avenue%2C%20Chestnut%20Hill%2C%20MA%2C%20US) produces a result of type "premise". So Google is storing both requests as separate entities unfortunately.

Comment: [Without a postal code](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D23%2520Commonwealth%2520Avenue%252C%2520Chestnut%2520Hill%252C%2520MA%252C%2520US) you get place ID `ChIJvSgFdl1444kRU7OhpzwJ-I8`, but [with postal code](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D23%2520Commonwealth%2520Avenue%252C%2520Chestnut%2520Hill%252C%2520MA%252002467%252C%2520US) you get place ID `EjQyMyBDb21tb253ZWFsdGggQXZlbnVlLCBDaGVzdG51dCBIaWxsLCBNQSAwMjQ2NywgVVNBIhoSGAoUChIJTVLln11444kR_uxpXjGKZukQFw` (interpolated). It sounds like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

With zip code:

https://geocoder.ca/23%20Commonwealth%20Avenue%2C%20Chestnut%20Hill%2C%20MA%2002467%2C%20US

- CHESTNUT HILL, MA » 23 COMMONWEALTH, CHESTNUT HILL, MA » 02467-1099 » 42.340075,-71.167546

  - 23 COMMONWEALTH AVE, CHESTNUT HILL, MA 02467-1099 ( 02467-1099 polygon ) Confidence Score: 1

Without zip:

https://geocoder.ca/23%20Commonwealth%20Avenue%2C%20Chestnut%20Hill%2C%20MA

- CHESTNUT HILL, MA » 23 COMMONWEALTH, CHESTNUT HILL, MA » 02467-1099 » 42.340075,-71.167546
- 23 COMMONWEALTH AVE, CHESTNUT HILL, MA 02467-1099 ( 02467-1099 polygon ) Confidence Score: 1

Both rooftop results.